# Web scraping with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I think this is an obvious question but still I cannot figure out how to grab text from an element.

I need to get the text "Yor credit balance is zero".
I'm trying with this:
Any help? Thank you.

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
  let credits = document.querySelector('#content > searchPanel > div > div:nth-child(6) > span > span:nth-child(2) > span.red-text').innerText
  return {
    credits
  }
  console.log(result);
})
```

Here the element

```
<div class="wrapper">


        <div id="content">

<section style="padding:0px 0;" id="searchPanel">

<div class="text-center">
        <br>
        <span class="red-text">
                <span class="red-text">
                    Your Credit Balance is zero.
                </span>
        </span>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Rob thank you for advise. But it's just the path of the element, how to copy all of this?

Comment: In inspector, right click and copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the selector, you might give it a try now!

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const selector = '#content > #searchPanel > div form span > span.red-text';
    let credits = document.querySelector(selector).innerText;
    return { credits };
})
console.log("Result:", result);
```

I'm testing against the following html

```
<html>
    <div id="content">
        <section id="searchPanel">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form action="/v2/lookups">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <span class="red-text">
                                        <span class="red-text">
                                        Your Credit Balance Is Zero
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</html>
```

Code to test against a local .html file:

```
const path = require("path");
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');    
(async() => {    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();    
    await page.goto(`file:${path.join(__dirname, 'test.html')}`);    
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
```

//this is the right path

```
        const selector = '#searchPanel > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > span > span';

        let credits = document.querySelector(selector).innerText;
        return { credits };
    })
    console.log("Result:", result);
})();
```

Comment: (node:20720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

Comment: Hey @Terry thank but didn't worked. what about document.getElementsByClassName?

Comment: You could try that for sure. I think the best approach is to get this working offline if you can, so you have a really quick testing cycle. I've been testing against a local html file, this is easy to do with puppeteer.

Comment: Yes, it worked offline. Maybe I'm forgetting some element. It was a huge code. I've upload the entire element here: https://ibb.co/k0LFXVD

Comment: Great, I'll see if I can find a solution. If we can just get the right offline html, it should work online too!

Comment: I've updated my answer with some new test html. Hopefully this corresponds more closely with your actual data.

Comment: Still null for me. What about use page.evaluate(() => window.find? Because I just need to use the string (Your Credit Balance is zero.) to check and go ahead or exit. If I put only #content inside the querySelector I get that string.

Comment: Thank for all answers @Terry. Now I got the right way to get the elements.